# How to reference a page-item from a tab

Tags: oracle, tabs, conditional-statements, oracle-apex

I have Oracle APEX 5.0.3.

I want to hide/show a tab with a condition referencing a page-item:
:P1_XXX = 1

Is it possible, that the page-items are not visible for the tab-condition?

The tab is not shown with condition
:P1_XXX = 1
and with condition
:P1_XXX = 0

The content of P1_XXX is 1.

Thank you very much!!

oradev2015

Comment: What is the condition type that you are using?

Comment: value of item / column in expression 1 = expression 2. expression 1 = :P1_XXX. expression 2 = 1

Comment: And in the "Expression 1" you used `P1_XXX` (without the colon) and in "Expression 2" you used `1` and if you check the session state the value of that item is '1' ?

Comment: In your comment you said that expression 1 = `:P1_XXX` - but this must be the name of the item, so remove the `:` (colon).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can still include an item in a condition even if it is hidden. Have you tried the `PL/SQL function body` type of condition? If not then try it. then in the PL/SQL section of your condition, enter the following codes:

```
  IF :P1_XXX = 1 OR :P1_XXX = 0 THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
  ELSE
       RETURN TRUE;
  END IF;
```